# Getting error while adding custom command for npm install step in Azure DevOps

Tags: reactjs, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have added npm install step in my Azure DevOps pipeline to build my react project, due to some dependency issue we used the `npm install --force` command locally, and same we tried in npm install step of the Azure DevOps pipeline, but it doesn't work. I'm not sure what is going wrong. Please help me with this.

[image: Custom Command][image: error log]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
Command and arguments: npm install --force
```

Enter

```
Command and arguments: install --force
```

Comment: Some extra clarification: As you are using the "npm custom" step, the "command and arguments" box only assumes that you add everything that comes after "npm"

Comment: Yes. It knows to run npm. You're passing it the command: "install" and the arguments "--force".